# unable to update <p id>

Tags: javascript, html

this code is supposed to take two numbers from the user and output the sum on a button press, but i am unable to make the contents of  change no matter what i do

```js
var x = Number(getElementById('input1').value);
var y = Number(getElementById('input2').value);
var z
document.getElementById('Result').innerHTML = x;

function gotime() {
  z = x + y
  document.getElementById('Result').innerHTML = " + z + "
}
```

```html
<html>
<h> <b>Adder</b>
  <h>
    <input type="number" name="input1" id=input1 size="10" /> <input type="number" name="input2" id="input2" size="10" />
    <p id="Result">Result</p>
    <button name="runner" value="runner" id="runner" onclick="gotime()"> Add </button>

</html>
```

Comment: It's `document.getElementById`

Comment: Click the Run code snippet button and observe the error(s) which result. Note that the assignment to `x` and `y` occur when the page loads, and therefore will not occur when the button is pressed. Also, the result will only ever show `+ z +`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing `document.` on both input fields -> `document.getElementById('input1')`

You are missing quotes on `id=input1`

Also varible in js are are insrted without quotes, or if you have some text infront or behind it should be `.innerHTM= "result" + z + "text";` and for only result its: `.innerHTML = z`

Also move your input fetching inside function, so it can be grab values on button click not on page load...

```js
function gotime() {
  var x = Number(document.getElementById('input1').value);
  var y = Number(document.getElementById('input2').value);
  var z
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = x;

  z = x + y
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = z
}
```

```html
<input type="number" name="input1" id="input1" size="10" /> 
<input type="number" name="input2" id="input2" size="10" />
<p id="result">Result</p>
<button name="runner" value="runner" id="runner" onclick="gotime()"> Add </button>
```